# Targeting error on Team Foundation

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a project build in framework 4.0 using several projects build with framework 3.5. It compiles and works without problem.
But when I'm trying to launch integration test using Team Foundation, I have the following message :
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1360) The referenced assembly "**" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".

I don't know why it mention "Profile=Client" because none of my project use it. How can I fix this ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looks same as this

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/510573/referenced-assembly-could-not-be-resolved-because-it-has-a-dependency-conflict

1) Make sure you that you are not using .NET RC version on the build server.

2) Make sure your target framework is set to full framework and not Client profile in the configuration you are trying to build on TFS. You might have it set in the Debug configuration but not in Release configuration.